# avoid repeated mysql connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

Im not sure if by including this script in on every page load if I am re-connecting to the database.

Is there a way to just connect once? Should I use a session to tell me whether the site is connected?

Example: here is my config.php

```
<?
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$db = 'demo';
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);
?>
```

Then on index.php I have at the top

```
<?
session_start();
require_once 'inc/config.php';
include_once 'inc/functions.php';
?>
```

Each time index.php is loaded, will the db connect unnecessarily each time? If so, what is a good method to avoid this?

Comment: Some APIs offer ["persistent connections"](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php), but you are in fact reconnecting on each page load. That usually isn't a problem though, and is the typical approach to take.

Comment: Persistent connections are somewhat exotic in PHP...

Answer (score 1):

> Im not sure if by including this script in on every page load if I am re-connecting to the database.

Yes you are.

> Is there a way to just connect once?

No.

> Should I use a session to tell me whether the site is connected?

That's impossible.

**There is nothing wrong with connecting on every page load.** That's how it works. Nothing to be worry of.